# Register external users using MSAL with Identity on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Problem:
In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Web app I Use the `services.AddSignIn(Configuration);` in my startup.cs (provided by the [Microsoft.Identity.Web 0.1.5-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web/0.1.5-preview?_src=template)) and I want to register a User upon logging in, the callback method `ExternalLoginInfo info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` always returns null.

Background:

- I have an application which uses [ASP.NET
  Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
  to register and store users. - all the users use their Microsoft
  accounts
- I wanted to enhance the app to use MS Graph API (to reach a Sharepoint
  site for some files), so I've modified the app to use the
  [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)
  for authentication against the Graph API.
- I've used [these MSAL
  tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/enable-webapp-signin/)
  to try the features out and the sign in went well, I could connect
  the graph API as well.

Details:
My appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "something.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "GUID",
    "ClientId": "GUID",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "GUID"
  }
```

Startup cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), u => u.MigrationsAssembly("DatabaseLayer.Core")));
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
            options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
        });

        services.AddOptions();


        services.AddSignIn(Configuration);
```

Question: What do I need to configure to get any externallogins returned in order to register the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by saving the `uid` and `utid` claims from the MSAL access token in the local user claims store. These claims are being looked up by the MSAL library when keying into their token store.

Code example in a Blazor 8 Web App template, in the file `Components\Account\Pages\ExternalLogin.razor` in function `OnValidSubmitAsync`:

```cs
private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync()
{
        ... 
    var claimsStore = GetClaimsStore();

    string? OptClaim(List<string> claimTypes) => 
        claimTypes.Select(s => externalLoginInfo.Principal.FindFirstValue(s))
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s is not null);

    const string tenantIdClaimType = "utid";
    const string tenantIdClaimTypeAlt = 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid";
    const string objectIdClaimType = "uid";
    const string objectIdClaimTypeAlt = 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier";

    var tenantId = OptClaim([tenantIdClaimType, tenantIdClaimTypeAlt]);
    var objectId = OptClaim([objectIdClaimType, objectIdClaimTypeAlt]);

    if (tenantId is not null) {
        await claimsStore.AddClaimsAsync(
            user, 
            [new(tenantIdClaimType, tenantId)], 
            default);
    }

    if (objectId is not null) {
        await claimsStore.AddClaimsAsync(
            user, 
            [new(objectIdClaimType, objectId)], 
            default);
    }
```

EDIT: and here's the definition for `GetClaimsStore` for completeness:

```cs
    private IUserClaimStore<ApplicationUser> GetClaimsStore() {
        if (!UserManager.SupportsUserClaim) {
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "The default UI requires a user store with claims support.");
        }
        return (IUserClaimStore<ApplicationUser>)UserStore;
    }
```

EDIT #2: It is also necessary to obtain the external login info from the MSAL-created `Cookies` scheme, since it doesn't use `Identity.External`, here is the modification to `OnInitializeAsync`:

```cs
    // This method is a slightly modified version of
    //    SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync
    private async Task<ExternalLoginInfo?> GetMsalInfo() {
        var auth = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies");
        var items = auth?.Properties?.Items;
        if (auth?.Principal == null || items == null 
            || !items.TryGetValue("LoginProvider", out var provider))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var providerKey = auth.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) 
            ?? auth.Principal.FindFirstValue("sub");
        if (providerKey == null || provider == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var providerDisplayName = 
            (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync())
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == provider)
            ?.DisplayName ?? provider;
        return new ExternalLoginInfo(
            auth.Principal, 
            provider, 
            providerKey, 
            providerDisplayName)
            {
                AuthenticationTokens = auth.Properties?.GetTokens(),
                AuthenticationProperties = auth.Properties,
            };
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
            ...

        var info = await GetMsalInfo();
        info ??= await SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

            ...
```

Comment: Many thanks for adding these! Also pls note, that my original question was 3 years ago, where I used a preview version of the nuget. Since then we went to the project's github and discussed the possible solutions. AFAIK now the original scenario is not a problem anymore.

Comment: It is, this particular scenario has hit me just a week ago while trying to do the exact same thing as you. And my changes are necessary even now for it to work.

Comment: Ohh I see. In this case I think maybe you should follow my link to github in the original answer, which leads to the bug report to let the devs know this is still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/133), it is not possible to catch external users using MSAL. Moreover it is not possible to use any internal users as well, because they would interfere with the logged in MSAL user.

So Microsoft's ASP.NET Core Identity framework is incompatible with their identity framework, nice. (Pity, this makes MSAL useless for me, and I cannot think of any business case where a productive application does not have to have any internal repository of users to work properly. Even if I only would need to store a user's setting I would use the identity framework for this purpose).